# .NET Core Build Fails, Can't find csc.dll file in MSBuild folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

Installed .NET Core 3.1 SDK from Microsoft.com/net/core

If I run 
`dotnet --version` it says: `3.1.101`

I run `dotnet new console -o myApp` and it successfully creates a console app in c:\myApp.

I change to the folder and try to run `dotnet run` or `dotnet run myapp` and I get the following error every time.

*C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.dll" is invalid. [C:\myApp\myApp.csproj] The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.*

I've checked the folder it mentions in the error message, and of course, there is no csc.dll file, just a csc.exe.

This is a clean project, with no modifications, immediately after running the installer `(dotnet-sdk-3.1.101-win-x64.exe)`

Not really sure where to go from here. How do I fix MSBuild to look for the .exe (or am I barking up the wrong tree?)

Comment: I've just went through the same steps you've mentioned and I didn't get the error you've mentioned - but I got version 3.1.100

Comment: Are you running VS IDE to compile your source code? If so, there's a link on MSDN to get you going.                                                   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am facing the same issue on linux. The error is "error MSB3082: Task failed because "csc.dll" was not found." Again, I can see csc.exe in folder but no csc.dll.